# AWS Glue - Can conditional triggers fire with conditional on jobs from another workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I am using the AWS Glue service with two separate workflows (let's say workflow A and workflow B).

I have created a conditional-type trigger in workflow B that watches jobs in workflow A and supposedly fires when they succeed. Can this trigger actually fire if it watches jobs from workflow A (i.e. a different workflow)?

I have tested this a few times, but it seems the jobs in workflow B that are supposed to be triggered by this specific trigger don't seem to run despite all jobs that are being watched succeeding.

I can't seem to find any information on this specific AWS Glue setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AWS docs it seems that triggers that start a workflow must be of one of the following types:

- Schedule
- On demand
- EventBridge event

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflows_overview.html

A solution to my problem might be to omit Workflows entirely and just create triggers and jobs.

Answer (score 0):

despite this being an old topic I come to give a more assertive response:

according to these [knowledge center post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-workflow-not-triggered) it's clear that conditional triggers only work when associated with the workflow of the conditional subject/trigger's predicate:

> You have a workflow with a job JOB_MAIN that's triggered by the trigger TEST_TR.
> The trigger TEST_TR is dependent on the completion of another job JOB_DEP that's not part of the current workflow.
> In this case, even if JOB_DEP completes successfully, and the trigger TEST_TR's predicate logic is met, the job JOB_MAIN isn't fired. The job isn't fired because the predicate condition is met by an agent that's not part of the same workflow.